# import and export data from asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

Hi I am trying to find a solution to export data from my database but i don't know what is the best approach .
simply, i will upgrade my project in the future and i don't want to lose my data plus maybe, i add some new tables in the future and maybe some columns to the current tables .

so what should i do with that ?

and if there is a solution to do that from asp.net it will be great as the project will be on the cloud.

i have tried to backup and restore database it self but its overriding the data and maybe its avoid to restore the data if i added some new tables

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it in code I think the easiest is to create ALTER statements for your modifications; building up a script that can update your database.

On startup of your website? you can check the version of the database with the necessary version and run the scripts (Starting with a backup...). You will need a place to store the version in your database for this to work.

There are also tools available (commercial) that can do this; but it is not scripted so it will be a manual process.